# how to use a random number counter in a Jquery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing around with if statements but I'm having some trouble. I want to pass random numbers to a variable and then be able to make something happen base on the clicking event.

Below is what I have played around with but it's not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $r;

  $('.cell').click(function() {
    $r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    if $($r == 3) {
      $(this).addClass('img');
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-color", "‎#708090").slideUp(150).slideDown(150);

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: `if $($r == 3)` should be `if ($r == 3)`. Why too many `$` ?

Comment: In order to view errors, open the developer console that comes with your browser (usually by pressing F12).

Comment: is this a typo error?

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and add html to show a [mcve]

Comment: @PrajwalBati - Please do *not* edit the code in a question (other than to tidy whitespace or move it into a runnable snippet). If you think you know what is wrong with it, post an answer.

Comment: Oh ok. My bad. I will mind that from now onwards.

Comment: Marked to close as typo

Comment: It works !!! Thanks for those eagle eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple typos here and there. I also added .removeClass to the conditional so you can remove the .img styling if the ran num isn't 3:

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
if (r == 3) {
    $(this).addClass('img');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('img');
    $(this).css("background-color", "#708090").slideUp(150).slideDown(150);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04m0fgxj/6/

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things is wrong in syntex. extra '$' and  ' })' .

```js
 $('.cell').click(function() {
   $r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
   //$r=3; // uncomment this for check addClass img
   if ($r == 3) {
     $(this).addClass('img');
   } else {
     $(this).css("background-color", "#708090").slideUp(150).slideDown(150);

   }

 });
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  height: 100px;
}
.img{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='cell'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code

var r;
    $(".cell").click(function(){
       r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            if (r == 3) {
                    $(this).addClass('img');
            } else {
                    $(this).css("background-color","#708090").slideUp(150).slideDown(150);

            }
    });

There is no necessary of declaring a variable in $
```